# Let $\mathcal{A}= \{A_n = \left(0, \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Prove that $\bigcup \mathcal{A}\subseteq (0,1)$.

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $\mathcal{A}= \{A_n = \left(0, \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Prove that $\bigcup \mathcal{A}\subseteq (0,1)$.

Can you verify this solution?

Let $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{A}$. This implies that $x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left(0, \frac{n}{n+1}\right)$, that is, $x \in \left(0, \frac{n}{n+1}\right)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But note that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\left(0, \frac{n}{n+1}\right) \subseteq (0, 1)$. Thus, $x \in (0, 1).$

Comment: Instead of for all n, you should say for that n.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $A_n=(0,\frac{n}{n+1})$ is increasing.

$\bigcup_n A_n=\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}A_n=\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(0,\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=\underset{n\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(0,1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=(0,1)\subseteq(0,1)$